Configure access between different applications using the same AAD App
For the same Application I have 2 running containers and an Azure App Service. All 3 of them are using the same AzureActiveDirectory authentication with the same service principal.
# Auth block for container apps
resource "azapi_resource" "ca_1_auth" {
  type      = "Microsoft.App/containerApps/authConfigs@2023-05-01"
  name      = "current"
  parent_id = azapi_resource.ca_1.id
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      globalValidation = {
        redirectToProvider          = "azureactivedirectory"
        unauthenticatedClientAction = "RedirectToLoginPage"
      }
      httpSettings = {
        requireHttps = true
      }
      identityProviders = {

        azureActiveDirectory = {
          enabled = true
          registration = {
            clientId = var.auth_service_principal_id
          }
        }
      }
      platform = {
        enabled = true
      }
    }
  })
}

# Auth block for app service
auth_settings {
    enabled                       = true
    unauthenticated_client_action = "RedirectToLoginPage"
    active_directory {
      client_id = var.auth_service_principal_id
    }
    default_provider = "AzureActiveDirectory"
    issuer           = "---"
  }

How can I authenticate all requests between these containers ? I am tyring to Grant Access such that the 2 containers can access the app service container

To enable two container apps to authenticate and communicate with an Azure App Service using the same Azure AD authentication, you should configure managed identities for the containers. Then, establish role assignments for these identities to access the App Service. Utilize Terraform to automate the creation and secure management of these resources.  @RazvanTataru
